# js link - open document in browser

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, jslink, js

I`v made a neat JS link and implied it to a document library that adds a image to a document that that have the archive field on "yes".

the problem is that now the office documents doesn’t open via web (office web access).

=== this is the code that overriide and send the link to the documents ===

```
   return "<a style = 'color: black; text-decoration:none' href='" + url + "'>" + ctx.CurrentItem.FileLeafRef + "&nbsp;<img src='http://portalaviv/planning/Style%20Library/archivesign.png' alt='Archive Document' title='Archive Document'/></a>";
}
else {

    return "<a style = 'color: black; text-decoration:none'  href='" + url + "'>" + ctx.CurrentItem.FileLeafRef +  "</a>";
```

---

It worked
   return "" + ctx.CurrentItem.FileLeafRef + "";

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a query Parameter to the url

```
ctx.CurrentItem.FileLeafRef + "?web=1"
```